# Mouse Sensitivity change in a Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

How can I change(decrease) the mouse sensitivity within a java swing and thus get the coordinates. Need to scale down the mouse movements within a swing window. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no such way to adjust mouse sensitivity. It is the job of the operating system.

What if you have two applications that want a different mouse sensitivity? What should the operating system then do, if it supported application-specific mouse sensitivity?

So, the question has no answer.

I don't understand what you mean by "thus get the coordinates". What coordinates are you referring to?